# TideSDK: is it possible to use mediaStream and webrtc ?

Tags: camera, webrtc, tidesdk, mediastreamsource

I would like to know if it is possible with TideSDK to use Camera, Microphone and all the webrtc stuff.

I tried with a simple example but it does not work; I'm wondering if it is just matter of enabling it or if it's not supported at all.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide examples of the code you have tried and a description of the behaviour you encountered?

Comment: i didn't anything special, just copied the first dummy example of webcam usage i found in google and followed the "hot to get started" of the documentation. i pasted in the index.html file the code and sunned through the application packager



is this :[link]http://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php[/link]

Comment: sorry i made some mess with the previous message. i used as example this code to use the camera [link]http://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php

Comment: It is generally regarded as good form to include the code in your question rather than link to it. Include your exact code and someone may help you...